# Why do Mormons believe they will become gods when they die?

Tags: abrahamic-religions, afterlife, gods

The LDS scriptures declare that the ultimate goal of a Mormon is to become a god and procreate for all eternity in their own worlds.

Why is the goal to become a god in their own world and rule over it?

Comment: THAT is more of a philosophical question, only answerable from either the premise that the LDS is a true religion (so ask god) or it is a mythology (so why do mythologies form how they do? Ask a psychologist or anthropologist). Either way, I don't think you'll get a proper answer here.

Comment: I would assume that since the classic Christian view was that we have a divine spark within us, and we are children of God, it could be logically extended that we become like God if we prove worthy. It's not the nuttiest thing I've heard, even if it isn't what I believe.